# template being deduced as wrong type with template variable

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++14, gcc5.2

So I have the following test code:

```
struct empty_value{
    template<typename T>
    T as(){ return T(0); }
};

template<typename T, typename U, typename F>
auto empty_func(empty_value lhs, empty_value rhs, F f) -> decltype(f(lhs.as<T>(), rhs.as<U>())){
    return f(lhs.as<T>(), rhs.as<U>());
}

template<typename T, typename U, template<typename, typename> class F>
static auto bind_empty_f = std::bind(empty_func<T, U, F<T, U>>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, F<T, U>{});

template<typename F>
void other_test_func(F&&){}

template<typename T, typename U, template<typename, typename> class F>
void test_func(){
    other_test_func(bind_empty_f<T, U, F>);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
struct my_add{
    decltype(auto) operator()(T lhs, U rhs){ return lhs + rhs; }
};

int main(){
    test_func<float, int, my_add>();
}
```

Which is derived from something I was actually working on. The problem arises on the line of `bind_empty_f`. But only when it is passed to `other_test_func`. When I try to assign it to a regular variable like this:

```
int main(){
    auto var = bind_empty_f<float, int, my_add>;
}
```

Everything is all cheery. But if I call `test_func` which tries to pass it to `other_test_func` I get an error that the underlying type returned by `std::bind` can't be converted to `float`. So it is trying to convert it to the return value of the actual function. I can't understand why. Where am I passing the function's return value?

---

### EDIT

if I call the function after setting a local variable to the value of `bind_empty_f` first it compiles:

```
int main(){
    auto var = bind_empty_f<float, int, my_add>;
    test_func<float, int, my_add>;
}
```

So the issue must be <s>to do with static initialization</s> a compiler bug.

#### EDIT2

As stated in the comments, this exact example compiles with other compilers but does not with the original tested compiler (GCC 5.2.0).

This is a bug in either GCC 5.2 or every other compiler tested.

So I guess the question becomes, is this standard conforming code?

Comment: clang++ and g++6 compile your code

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki [coliru doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c991cbc59cc1455)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki coliru's version of g++ reports 5.2.0, so it must be a compiler bug

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I confirm, it compiles with clang 3.7.0, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc89de32dd59ef90

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a bug in the development version of gcc. It would make an interesting test for their test suite, but is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that yet.  Please provide the exact compiler and version, together with the compiler error messages, and the lines they refer to.  There are a few errors above (your type deduction of `F&&f`'s call is wrong), and your use of `std::bind` is usually a bad sign (it has quirky self-interaction).  I also see what could be some rvalue category errors, which depending on how rvalue aware `bind` is could give you some issues.  `bind_empty_f` only accepts an rvalue as the 3rd argument, which should only be passed if invoked in an rvalue context.

Comment: @MatthieuM. fair enough vote

Comment: @Yakk those aren't rvalue references, they're universal references. Though they could be deduced as rvalue references (they aren't in this case). It is definitely a compiler error. P.S. why do you say my type deduction of `f`s call is wrong?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode You may intend them to be universal references, but you are incorrect.  `empty_func<T, U, F<T, U>>` passes `F<T,U>` as the 3rd type argument, which forces the 3rd function argument to be `F<T,U> &&f` exactly.  Forwarding references (aka universal references) only work "simply" in a type deduction context; you are not doing such type deduction.

Comment: @Yakk: I have not concluded anything; I believe it is a bug, based on the fact that other versions of gcc compile the code as intended and clang also does. Of course, those other compilers/versions could be wrong and only the newest gcc be correct; I find it unlikely, but hey, I'm wrong often enough.

Comment: @Yakk ah, yes. I didn't think about the fact it was explicitly declared, I'll change it to an lvalue (as to not arise a different error). It still wouldn't cause the error I am getting though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm just saying that "one compiler builds something, others do not" is weak evidence that one of those compilers has a bug.  (The code may also be ill formed with no diagnostic required, in which case no compiler has a bug).  Closing it simply because it works in some compilers is premature; especially when messing around with tangled code `std::bind`s.  I will admit the question is far from a simple, minimal example, but there is some hope we can clean it up and find out what is actually going on.

Comment: @Yakk: You might think of it as a gut feeling; g++-5.1 also accepts the code (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bac7fd419b6d6332), which makes me think that the latest release broke something. As I said I may be wrong, of course, in which case I'll be happy to retract my vote or vote to re-open as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of your problem:

```
template<class T> struct tag {};

template<typename T>
static auto bind_empty_f = tag<T>{};

template<typename T>
decltype(bind_empty_f<T>) test_func(){
  return 3.14f;
}
```

then we simply `test_func<float>()` and it returns `3.14f`.  If we `test_func<int>()` it returns `3`.

If we first do a `bind_empty_f<float>`, instead `test_func<float>` generates an error.

The type deduced for `bind_empty_f<T>` when it is called within another template is set to `T` and not to the type of the right hand side of the expression.

If you call it directly, *and* the type hasn't already been calculated (there seems to be a cache), then the correct type is deduced, and my `test_func` fails to build (as it tries to convert `3.14f` to a `bind` expression type and fails).

This is definitely a problem with the compiler.  You can work around it by replacing the `auto` in `bind_empty_f` with a `std::decay_t<decltype(stuff_on_rhs)>`.

Note that there are other problems with some of your bind expressions, but they are not central to this issue.

[live example compiling (wrongly)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e05a1baa4be08a9), [live example not compiling (correctly)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97794ff7132be4c2).